# Serializing Objects to Delimited Files Part II

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, reflection

This is a follow up to my previous question: [Serializing objects to delimited files](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/128539/serializing-objects-to-delimited-files)

I've added some feature enhancements, and based on suggestions from rolfl in chat, I've fixed up a couple inconsistencies with the serializer.

First, if you don't mark any properties with `DelimitedColumnAttribute`, I added a `DelimitedIgnoreAttribute` which will *blacklist* columns instead. For objects with no properties marked with either, all properties are serialized instead, with the following exception:

### No collection properties (except `System.String`) are serialized, period.

You can also replace invalid values in names/fields (values that have the `RowDelimiter` or `ColumnDelimiter` in them) with whatever you specify.

You can choose whether or not to include the header row.

You can choose to quote values/names. If you choose to, all values/names are quoted.

You can choose how double-quotes are escaped (necessary for quoted values/names).

DelimitedSerializer.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a serializer that will serialize arbitrary objects to files with specific row and column separators.
/// </summary>
public class DelimitedSerializer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The string to be used to separate columns.
    /// </summary>
    public string ColumnDelimiter { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The string to be used to separate rows.
    /// </summary>
    public string RowDelimiter { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If not null, then sequences in values and names which are identical to the <see cref="ColumnDelimiter"/> will be replaced with this value.
    /// </summary>
    public string InvalidColumnReplace { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If not null, then sequences in values and names which are identical to the <see cref="RowDelimiter"/> will be replaced with this value.
    /// </summary>
    public string InvalidRowReplace { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If true, a trailing <see cref="ColumnDelimiter"/> will be included on each line. (Some legacy systems require this.)
    /// </summary>
    public bool IncludeTrailingDelimiter { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If true, an empty row will be included at the end of the response. (Some legacy systems require this.)
    /// </summary>
    public bool IncludeEmptyRow { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If true, then all values and columns will be quoted in double-quotes.
    /// </summary>
    public bool QuoteValues { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If not null, then double quotes appearing inside a value will be escaped with this value.
    /// </summary>
    public string DoubleQuoteEscape { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// If true, then a header row will be output.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IncludeHeader { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes an object to a delimited file. Throws an exception if any of the property names, column names, or values contain either the <see cref="ColumnDelimiter"/> or the <see cref="RowDelimiter"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of the object to serialize.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="items">A list of the items to serialize.</param>
    /// <returns>The serialized string.</returns>
    public string Serialize<T>(List<T> items)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ColumnDelimiter))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The property '{nameof(ColumnDelimiter)}' cannot be null or an empty string.");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RowDelimiter))
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"The property '{nameof(RowDelimiter)}' cannot be null or an empty string.");
        }

        var result = new ExtendedStringBuilder();

        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
            .Select(p => new
            {
                Attribute = p.GetCustomAttribute<DelimitedColumnAttribute>(),
                Info = p
            })
            .Where(x => x.Attribute != null)
            .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute.Order)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Attribute.Name)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Info.Name)
            .ToList();

        if (properties.Count == 0)
        {
            properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
                .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<DelimitedIgnoreAttribute>() == null)
                .Select(p => new
                {
                    Attribute = new DelimitedColumnAttribute { Name = p.Name },
                    Info = p
                })
                .Where(x => x.Attribute != null)
                .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute.Order)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Attribute.Name)
                .ThenBy(x => x.Info.Name)
                .ToList();
        }

        Action<string, string, string> validateCharacters = (string name, string checkFor, string humanLocation) =>
        {
            if (name.Contains(checkFor))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException($"The {humanLocation} string '{name}' contains an invalid character: '{checkFor}'.");
            }
        };

        var columnLine = new ExtendedStringBuilder();

        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            if (property.Info.PropertyType.IsArray || (property.Info.PropertyType != typeof(string) && property.Info.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var name = property.Attribute?.Name ?? property.Info.Name;

            if (InvalidColumnReplace != null)
            {
                name = name.Replace(ColumnDelimiter, InvalidColumnReplace);
            }
            if (InvalidRowReplace != null)
            {
                name = name.Replace(RowDelimiter, InvalidRowReplace);
            }
            if (DoubleQuoteEscape != null)
            {
                name = name.Replace("\"", DoubleQuoteEscape);
            }

            validateCharacters(name, ColumnDelimiter, "column name");
            validateCharacters(name, RowDelimiter, "column name");

            if (columnLine.HasBeenAppended)
            {
                columnLine += ColumnDelimiter;
            }

            if (QuoteValues)
            {
                columnLine += "\"";
            }
            columnLine += name;
            if (QuoteValues)
            {
                columnLine += "\"";
            }
        }

        if (IncludeTrailingDelimiter)
        {
            columnLine += ColumnDelimiter;
        }

        if (IncludeHeader)
        {
            result += columnLine;
        }

        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            var row = new ExtendedStringBuilder();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                if (property.Info.PropertyType.IsArray || (property.Info.PropertyType != typeof(string) && property.Info.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null))
                {
                    continue;
                }

                var value = property.Info.GetValue(item)?.ToString();

                if (property.Info.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime) || property.Info.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime?))
                {
                    value = ((DateTime?)property.Info.GetValue(item))?.ToString("u");
                }

                if (value != null)
                {
                    if (InvalidColumnReplace != null)
                    {
                        value = value.Replace(ColumnDelimiter, InvalidColumnReplace);
                    }
                    if (InvalidRowReplace != null)
                    {
                        value = value.Replace(RowDelimiter, InvalidRowReplace);
                    }
                    if (DoubleQuoteEscape != null)
                    {
                        value = value.Replace("\"", DoubleQuoteEscape);
                    }

                    validateCharacters(value, ColumnDelimiter, "property value");
                    validateCharacters(value, RowDelimiter, "property value");
                }

                if (row.HasBeenAppended)
                {
                    row += ColumnDelimiter;
                }

                if (QuoteValues)
                {
                    row += "\"";
                }
                row += value;
                if (QuoteValues)
                {
                    row += "\"";
                }
            }

            if (IncludeTrailingDelimiter)
            {
                row += ColumnDelimiter;
            }

            if (result.HasBeenAppended)
            {
                result += RowDelimiter;
            }

            result += row;
        }

        return result;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an instance of the <see cref="DelimitedSerializer"/> setup for Tab-Separated Value files.
    /// </summary>
    public static DelimitedSerializer TsvSerializer => new DelimitedSerializer
    {
        ColumnDelimiter = "\t",
        RowDelimiter = "\r\n",
        InvalidColumnReplace = "\\t",
        IncludeHeader = true
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an instance of the <see cref="DelimitedSerializer"/> setup for Comma-Separated Value files.
    /// </summary>
    public static DelimitedSerializer CsvSerializer => new DelimitedSerializer
    {
        ColumnDelimiter = ",",
        RowDelimiter = "\r\n",
        InvalidColumnReplace = "\\u002C",
        IncludeHeader = true
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an instance of the <see cref="DelimitedSerializer"/> setup for Pipe-Separated Value files.
    /// </summary>
    public static DelimitedSerializer PsvSerializer => new DelimitedSerializer
    {
        ColumnDelimiter = "|",
        RowDelimiter = "\r\n",
        InvalidColumnReplace = "\\u007C",
        IncludeHeader = true
    };

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns an instance of the <see cref="DelimitedSerializer"/> from the RFC 4180 specification. See: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180
    /// </summary>
    public static DelimitedSerializer Rfc4180Serializer => new DelimitedSerializer
    {
        ColumnDelimiter = ",",
        RowDelimiter = "\r\n",
        IncludeHeader = true,
        IncludeTrailingDelimiter = true,
        QuoteValues = true,
        DoubleQuoteEscape = "\"\""
    };
}
```

DelimitedColumnAttribute.cs:

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a column which can be used in a <see cref="DelimitedSerializer"/>.
/// </summary>
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DelimitedColumnAttribute : Attribute
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The name of the column.
    /// </summary>
    public string Name { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The order the column should appear in.
    /// </summary>
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

DelimitedIgnoreAttribute.cs:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class DelimitedIgnoreAttribute : Attribute
{
}
```

Comment: Could you also post an example how to use this and maybe some results?

Comment: @t3chb0t Yeah, when I get home from work I will.

Comment: ok, and maybe the `ExtendedStringBuilder` too ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t That's in a different question on here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me the `Serialize` method is too big. I'd split it in three parts.

The first part would be the reflection stuff where you read and sort the properties - this could be a new class like `ElementReflector` or maybe an extension.

The second part (maybe a method) would be the first `foreach` that I cannot figure out what it does.

The third part (maybe a method too) would be the second `foreach` that does something but I'm not sure what.

Putting them in methods would give them a meaning without you having to explain each time what they are good for.

```
public string Serialize<T>(List<T> items)
{
    ... prepare sort etc properties

    var result = new StringBuilder()
        .Append(CreateHeader(properties))
        .Append(SerializeData(items, properties));

    return result.ToString();
}
```

---

**if**s

```
if (property.Info.PropertyType.IsArray || (property.Info.PropertyType != typeof(string) && property.Info.PropertyType.GetInterface(typeof(IEnumerable<>).FullName) != null))
```

You could use a variable for that to tell what this condition is for. Or even create an extension for it.

The same applies for many other `if`s where the intentions is not clear.

Besides you use the same condition twice (in both loops) so an extenstion would definitely help.

---

**ColumnDelimiter & RowDelimiter**

If these two properties cannot be null you should requrie them via the constructor instead of checking them in the `Serilize` method.

Also if the user can change them later then you should check the values in the property setter instead of throwing exeptions later and causing astonishment why isn't this working.

---

**DelimitedColumnAttribute**

It is possible to create an invalid attribute because there is no construtor that enforces the required values. I guess the name is required if the attribute is specified.

---

**properties**

> ```
> properties = typeof(T).GetProperties()
>   .Where(x => x.GetCustomAttribute<DelimitedIgnoreAttribute>() == null)
>   .Select(p => new
>   {
>       Attribute = new DelimitedColumnAttribute { Name = p.Name },
>       Info = p
>   })
>   .Where(x => x.Attribute != null)
>   .OrderBy(x => x.Attribute.Order)
>   .ThenBy(x => x.Attribute.Name)
>   .ThenBy(x => x.Info.Name)
>   .ToList();
> ```

You are always adding the attribute so this `.Where(x => x.Attribute != null)` isn't necessary.

As the `Attribute.Name` is equal `p.Name` either the `.ThenBy(x => x.Attribute.Name)` or `.ThenBy(x => x.Info.Name)` can be removed.

Comment: The first foreach builds the header, the second builds all the rows.

Comment: There are no required values in `DelimitedColumnAttribute`. It can be left empty.